# How do I distinguish between Ctrl+C vs regular unbind using EventMachine?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

Is there a good way to distinguish between when I do a Ctrl+C to manually close all connections, and when a client disconnects from my server? They both seem to call the `unbind` method.

When I manually shut down using Ctrl+C, I can probably try to reconnect with the peers I'm connected to when I start back up because they are still online. If a client disconnects from me I don't want to try reconnecting to it for a while, because it probably shut down even though I'm still up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the answer form the EventMachine google group.

http://groups.google.com/group/eventmachine/browse_thread/thread/92d92d7d101e933c

Basically you can use `EM.next_tick` to run extra stuff that you wouldn't want to do on a ctrl-c (since the reactor shuts down and there is no next tick).

Here is my unbind method:

```
  def unbind
    # temporarily disconnect in a way that would reconnect next time
    @peer.update_attribute :connected, false

    # really disconnect, this is not called on ctrl-c
    EM.next_tick do
      @peer.destroy
    end
  end
```

Comment: Really nice ! that's a question I asked myself many times but I never bothered me enough to seek a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+C is a signal to the running process, you can TRAP it, and it will looks like:

```
interrupted = false

trap("INT") { interrupted = true }


if interrupted
   # CTRL+C pressed
end
# rest of program
```

Similar way you can trap more signals, like HUP or KILL

Comment: Does this trap work inside the `unbind` method, or has it already been trapped by then?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/em/connection.rb#L199
Here what I'v found in sources, so it looks like you can override the undbind behavior.

Comment: Hmm...yep I've overridden `unbind` but it appears too late.  Eventmachine has already trapped the ctrl-c before entering `unbind`.  I also tried overriding `close_connection` but it looks like eventmachine doesn't call this directly - your own can but it doesn't by default.